# Action creator is being dispatched but the new state is not showing in store

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I have written a server and wired up React with Redux, also made use of container-componenent-seperation. The first action `fetchSnus()` is successfully dispatched, the selectors also seem to work, but for some reason all the actions that I call after the first rendering, such as `fetchSnu()` (that only fetches ONE single snu-object) e.g. is not accessible for me in the store, meaning: after mapping state and dispatch to props not accessible for me under `this.props`. I really don't understand why!

You can see the whole project here: https://github.com/julibi/shonagon

This is my container ReadSingleSnuContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchSnus, fetchSnu, setToRead, createSnu, getSnusMatchingKeyword } from '../../actions/index';
import { unreadSnus, randomFirstSnu } from '../../selectors/index';
import ReadSingleSnu from './ReadSingleSnu';

class ReadSingleSnuContainer extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchSnus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReadSingleSnu { ...this.props } />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    snus: state.snus,
    randomFirstSnu: randomFirstSnu(state),
    candidate: state.candidate
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchSnus: () => dispatch(fetchSnus()),
    getSnusMatchingKeyword,
    fetchSnu,
    setToRead,
    createSnu
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReadSingleSnuContainer);
```

This is my component ReadSingleSnu.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './ReadSingleSnu.css'

import Typist from 'react-typist';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

export default class ReadSingleSnu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showTitles: false };
  }
  renderRandomFirstSnu() {
    const { randomFirstSnu } = this.props;
    const { showTitles } = this.state;
    // preselect a keyword
    // dispatch the action that searches for other keywords (action I)

    if(randomFirstSnu) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3><Typist cursor={ { show: false } }>{ randomFirstSnu.title }</Typist></h3>
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="snu"
            transitionAppear={ true }
            transitionAppearTimeout={ 1000 }
            transitionEnter={ false }
            transitionLeave={ false }
          >
            <p>{ randomFirstSnu.text }</p>
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          { !showTitles ? (
            <div>
              <button>Some other</button>
              <button onClick={ () => this.handleDoneReading(randomFirstSnu) }>Done reading, next</button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="keywords"
              transitionAppear={ true }
              transitionAppearTimeout={ 1000 }
              transitionEnter={ false }
              transitionLeave={ false }
            >
              <ul>{ randomFirstSnu.keywords.map((keyword, idx) => 
                <li key={ idx }>
                  <button onClick={ () => this.fetchNextSnu(randomFirstSnu) }>
                    { keyword }
                  </button>
                </li>) }
              </ul> 
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          )
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div>Loading ...</div>
  }

  handleDoneReading(snu) {
    const { setToRead, getSnusMatchingKeyword } = this.props;
    const id = snu._id; 
    if (snu.keywords.length > 0 && setToRead) {
      // setToRead(id, snu);

      this.setState({ showTitles: true });

      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * snu.keywords.length);
      const randomKeyword = snu.keywords[randomIndex];
      console.log('This is the randomKeyword :', randomKeyword);
      getSnusMatchingKeyword(randomKeyword);
    } else {
        console.log('Here will soon be the select random next snu action :)');
    } 
  }   

  render() {
    console.log('ReadSingleSnu, this.props: ', this.props);
    return (
      <div className={style.App}>
        <div>{ this.renderRandomFirstSnu() }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my actions file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_SNUS = 'FETCH_SNUS';
export const FETCH_SNU = 'FETCH_SNU';
export const SET_TO_READ = 'SET_TO_READ';
export const CREATE_SNU = 'CREATE_SNU';

export function getSnusMatchingKeyword(keyword) {
  const request = axios.get(`/snus/keyword/${keyword}`);
  return {
    type: GET_SNUS_MATCHING_KEYWORD,
    payload: request
  };
}

export function fetchSnus() {
    const request = axios.get('/snus');
    return {
        type: FETCH_SNUS,
        payload: request
    };
}

export function fetchSnu(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`/snus/${id}`);
    return {
        type: FETCH_SNU,
        payload: request
    };
}

export function setToRead(id, snu) {
  const request = axios.patch(`/snus/${id}`, { title: snu.title, text: snu.text, keywords: snu.keywords, read: true });
    return {
      type: SET_TO_READ,
      payload: request
    }
}

export function createSnu(object) {
  const request = axios.post('/snus', object);
    return {
      type: CREATE_SNU,
      payload: request
    };
}
```

A Reducer:

```
import { FETCH_SNUS, FETCH_SNU, SET_TO_READ, CREATE_SNU } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_SNUS:
      return [ ...state, ...action.payload.data ];
    case FETCH_SNU:
      return [ ...state, ...action.payload.data ];
    case SET_TO_READ:
      return [ ...state, ...action.payload.data ];
    case CREATE_SNU:
      return [...state, ...action.payload.data ];
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

I tested all endpoints via Postman and they work. So that should not be the problem… Please help! I cannot find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I cut the method that contains fetchSnu() out, but believe it doesn't work. The same as fetchSnu() would be getSnusMatchingKeyword() ……

Comment: Axios methods return promises. You're sending those promises into the action creators and then immediately into the redux store, using the object spread operator. You probably want to wait for the promise to resolve, using `then`, and then send the resolved value (not the promise itself) into the action creator.